# Incorrect internet time in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: indicator, timezone

I have Ubuntu 13.10 set to use the time "automatically from the internet" (whatever that means). However it is running 3 minutes slower than the actual time.

How can I fix this permanently? I thought the point of getting time from a time server is that the machine would sync on a reasonably regular basis (perhaps once a minute, or even more frequently).

I have the `ntp` service installed already.

Answer (score 4):

I found that `ntpdate` was the fix I was looking for.

Two steps:

1) Turn off automatic updates on the clock settings.

2) Use the command

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

According to Ubuntu, running ntp on a desktop (non-server) machine is not recommended.

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/NTP.html

But also at that site, it outlines how to run ntpdate as a daily cron job

> With your favorite editor, as root, create a file `/etc/cron.daily/ntpdate` containing:

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

> `The file`/etc/cron.daily/ntpdate`must also be executable.`

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/ntpdate
```

BTW, I still don't know what the "automatically from the internet" means either.  As it very often fails, even when connected to the internet.

Comment: Hmm. I get the following response when I try `ntpdate`:

`27 Jan 09:31:39 ntpdate[3512]: no server suitable for synchronization found`.

(As an aside, I also note that manually editing the time on my system doesn't work properly. If I change the time and close the dialog immediately, the changes aren't saved. I have to leave the dialog open for a minute or so for the change to propagate to the indicator, then it's safe to close the dialog.)

Comment: The "No server suitable" error generally means either the ntp server is down or you have no internet connection.  Try adding pool.ntp.org to the list of servers `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com pool.ntp.org`

Comment: I really like the idea of using the cron job to make sure that gets synced nightly or something. I have 14 ubuntu desktop instances running test cases and randomly one of them every now and then has the time 18 minutes off. weird behavior, but i will fix by putting this script in a cron: `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install the `ntp` service instead. I've found that with it the clock the time may not be accurate all the *time* so it's better if using some kind of service to take care of this. You can install it just typing:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

This will install a ntp server that will take care of the time synchronization. Disable the option in the time indicator and you are good to go.

Comment: I already have `npt` installed. Updated question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Did you disable the "automatically from the internet" option and your hardware clock is accurate?

Comment: No, as stated in the original question. I'm guessing the problem is something to do with how often the system syncs with the time server.

Comment: No, the problem is locally, no clock drift apart if there isn't a problem locally. You should check the `/etc/adjtime` file to find if the hardware clock correction are too high. It doesn't matter how many times you sync the clock if locally it will start to differ.